# Typescript: declare a parameter or property as one of the keys in a known object

Tags: typescript

I'm fairly new to TypeScript, and I've been trying to refactor some code.

Considering I have an object defined as such:

```
const Operators = {
    equal: '=',
    not_equal: '!=',
    less: '<',
    less_or_equal: '<=',
    greater: '>',
    greater_or_equal: '>=',
    contains: '~'
};
```

And then I have a class defined as such:

```
class Query {
    // I want to limit this to the keys defined in Operator
    operator: string;

    constructor(operator: string) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    getOperatorValue: string {
        return Operators[this.operator];
    }
}
```

How can I enforce that the parameter "operator" be one of the keys of `Operators`?

I get the following error against the line inside `getOperatorValue()`:

```
Error: TS7017:Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ equal: string; not_equal: string; less: string; less_or_equal: string; greater: string; greater...' has no index signature.
```

This is using Typescript 2.4.2.

Comment: You could solve the problem by typing `const Operators: { [key:string]: string } = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for the `keyOf` operator, [introduced in 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) and [documented with index types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types). Simply, `function foo<T>(bar: T, key: keyof T)` ensure that `key` will always be a known key from `T`. It provides an easy way to [type-safely use string indexers](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/01/06/typescript-2-1-keyof-and-lookup-types), among other uses in the type system.

The docs show examples of using `keyOf` to implement a type-safe `Partial` class:

```
type Readonly<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P];
}
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Turns out I needed this: `operator: keyof typeof Operators;` because I have `Operators` defined as a `const` not a `type`

Comment: I've never mixed those two before, but it's good to know you can and they work as expected. :)